# Linear Algebra- If $AB=BA$, does $(A+B)(A-B) = A^2 - B^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is as follows:

If $AB=BA$, does $(A+B)(A-B) = A^2 - B^2$?
is the above always true? (if $AB=BA$)

I thought of a counter example, where both $A$ and $B$ are equal to the $2\times 2$ identity matrices,

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

then $AB=BA$ holds true. However, $(A+B)(A-B) = A^2 -B^2$ does not hold true. 
Is this an acceptable counter example?

Comment: How is this a counterexample? $A-B = 0, so (A+B)\cdot 0 = 0$ is true.

Comment: Oh my I was too focused on the proof I couldn't see that

Comment: Note $(A+B)(A-B) = A^2-AB + BA -B^2=A^2-B^2 +(BA-AB)$

Comment: I guess it is only true if we are allowed to use the distributive law (e.g. if $A,B$ are elements of an arbitrary ring). Since only then we can evaluate the expression $(A+B)(A-B)$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not acceptable, because if $AB=BA$, then $$(A+B)(A-B)=A^2-B^2,$$ with the exact same proof as in the case of numbers.